# When would CBCentralManager's state ever be powered on but still give me a "not powered on" warning?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I keep getting this error when I run my app that uses CoreBluetooth on an iPhone 5: `<CBConcreteCentralManager: 0x2007d590> is not powered on`

But when I call `state` on my program's one and only CBCentralManager object, it returns 5, which is CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn. So it's powered on, yet I get this error. The iPhone's Bluetooth is also enabled.

Just in general, when would this ever happen? I don't even know what is going on when the program runs because I'm getting what looks like conflicting messages.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to initially wait until the centralManager gets the callback from `centralManagerDidUpdateState:` when you're app boots up. Then every other time, I recommend checking the state prior to doing any centralManager calls. You're most likely calling scan or retrieve before the central has had a chance to update. Ensure you only call methods after you know it's on. You will not get the error if you wrap each call in if statements that check the state first.

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
   if(central.state==CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)
   {
      //Now do your scanning and retrievals
   }
}
```

Otherwise just wrap your central inside a state check before each call:

```
if(yourCentral.state==CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)
{
//you're good to go on calling centralManager methods
}
```

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Thanks.

Comment: This solved the issue for me thank you. For some reason this started happening to me when I upgraded to Xcode 5 GM simulator.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Apple is no longer supporting BLE simulator support in Xcode 5

Comment: I think it was never updating the state because it saw no BLE devices nearby. When I asked the question, I didn't know that basically nothing but iPhones and heart monitors use BLE, and I was trying to make it see my car's Bluetooth stereo.

Comment: Also, I was not using the simulator.

Comment: This helped me to solve warning, Do I need to check other state like CBCentralManagerStateResetting before performing BLE operation?