# CBCentralManager state 5, App crashed

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-5, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I am trying to connect a heart rate monitor with my app and it is working properly in 4S and iPAD 3, but now I am testing it with iPhone 5, in that case it is giving me crash, I have followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118534/when-would-cbcentralmanagers-state-ever-be-powered-on-but-still-give-me-a-not) also but no help. Please see the attached device log for any help. Please suggest.[image: Device Log]

Thanks

Comment: can u pls paste some code whatever u have written in Delegates methods. specially in "- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
"

Comment: - (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    if (manager.state==CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)
    {        
        self.isBluetoothDeviceConnected = [self isLECapableHardware];
        if (self.isBluetoothDeviceConnected == NO)
        {
            NSLog(@"Bluetooth off");
        }
        else
        {
            self.isBluetoothDeviceConnected = YES;
            
            [self startScan];
        }
    }
}

Comment: what is "manager" here in "manager.state". why not u r using central as u get a reference if CBCentralManager reference in "central" object

Comment: Try this :

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central { if (central.state==CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) { self.isBluetoothDeviceConnected = [self isLECapableHardware]; if (self.isBluetoothDeviceConnected == NO) { NSLog(@"Bluetooth off"); } else { self.isBluetoothDeviceConnected = YES; [self startScan]; } } }

Comment: i have tried this also but no luck, manager is the reference of CBCentralManager object, Also below is my startScan method: - (void) startScan
{
    if (self.manager.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)
    {
        if (self.isBluetoothDeviceConnected == YES)
        {
            NSLog(@"Start scan called");
            
            [self.manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180D"]]options:nil];
        }
    }
}